# Nodejs, bcrypt async, mongoose login

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, postman

I have the following code for the **user model**

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({

_id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true,
    minlength: 3,

},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true
}

})
```

Then for **hashing the password** i have this code

```
UserSchema.pre('save', function (next) {


if (this.isModified('password')){

    bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt)=>{

        bcrypt.hash(this.password, salt, (err, hash)=>{
            this.password = hash;
            next();
        })

    });
}
next();

})
```

Then for checking the **hash against the input value from user** i have the following code

```
userSchema.statics.comparePassword = function(password){
    let user = this;
    return bcrypt.compareAsync(password, user.password)
}
```

So when it comes to the **usage of all** of these pieces of code i have the following

```
async loginUser(req, res) {
    try{
        const {email, password} = req.body
        const user = await User.findOne({
            email: req.body.email
        })
        if(!user){
            return res.status(403).send({
                error: "Incorrect details email"
            })
        }
        const isPassValid = await user.comparePassword(password)
       }catch(err){
        res.status(403).send({
            error: "The bid deal happened"
        })
     }
}
```

So I've tried searching on google and on this forum to find the answers but everything seems to be outdated or not working particularly for my situation. This code always sends "The bid deal happened", i've tried to debug it from all sides but its still unsuccessful.

**The question is** how to make it work? so that i can compare the passwords in the right way

**P.S** I've tried changing from compareAsync to compareSync, shows no effect

Comment: this looks incomplete, try turning `set DEBUG=* && node <script>` , console.log more information, and use node inspect to debug step by step..  there are tons of answers on how to login users using mongoose etc.. catching en err but outputting an message that has no useful information is bad.. try logging the error to the console..

Comment: hello this line "return bcrypt.compareAsync(password, user.password)" is compare or compareSync?

Comment: did console.log(bcrypt.compareSync(password, user.password)) but nothing shows up, changed to just "compare" nothing shows up.

Comment: the compare function takes a third argument that is a call back bcrypt.compare(password, user.password, function(err, res) {
    return res;
});

Comment: I've tried with callback it doesnt change anything anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You encrypt the password when the value is changed, but not when you insert a new mongo document, you can check this with `document.isNew`.

I have updated your save method to the follow.

```
UsersSchema.pre('save', function (next) {
    let user = this;

    if (this.isModified('password') || this.isNew) {
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
            if (err) {
                return next(err);
            }

            bcrypt.hash(user.password, salt, (err, hash) => {
                if (err) {
                    return next(err);
                }

                user.password = hash;
                next();
            });
        });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

Also, `Schema.statics` is used to serve `static` methods. The `this` context will not return the user, thus making `this.password` undefined. To populate the instances of your schema with methods, you have to append them to the `Schema.methods` object.

I have used `bcrypt.compare` in the past, I dont know if `bcrypt.compareAsync` is a valid method because the first one is already async. And if it was async, it wouldnt directly return a value. Compare requires a callback.

```
UsersSchema.methods.comparePassword = function (password, callback) {
    bcrypt.compare(password, this.password, (err, isMatch) => callback(err, isMatch));
};
```

To compare the password, u can do something like the following:

```
const { email, password } = req.body

User.findOne({
    email: email,
}, (err, user) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    if (user) {
        user.comparePassword(password, (err, match) => {
            if (match && !err) {
                // match
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks man, just needed to change from statics to methods and it worked. I just prefer to async await rather than call back functions everywhere :)